# riverpod FutureProvider will keep firing after adding .family modifier

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

so I have future provider like this

```
final additionalCostsProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose.family<List<ExtraCost>, List<String>>((ref, cartCodes) {
  final cartAPI = ref.watch(cartAPIProvider);
  return cartAPI.getAdditionalCosts(cartCodes: cartCodes);
});
```

as you can see, I pass cart codes ( `List<String>` ) as a parameter for my `FutureProvider`

and then I use it like this

```
@override
  Widget build(context, ref) {
    final List<String> cartCodes = carts.map((cart) => cart.code).toList();
    final additionalCostsProviderAsynValue = ref.watch(additionalCostsProvider(cartCodes));

    return Scaffold(
      body: additionalCostsProviderAsynValue.when(
        loading: () => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        error: (error, stackTrace) {
          return ErrorDisplay(
            onButtonClicked: () => ref.refresh(additionalCostsProvider(cartCodes)),
          );
        },
        data: (results) {

          return Container();

        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

and then it will make my app request to the server over and over again.

I believe the problem is on the `.family` modifier. because if change the `FutureProvider` without using `.family` like the code below, the problem will not occurred.

```
final additionalCostsProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose<List<ExtraCost>>((ref) {
  final cartAPI = ref.watch(cartAPIProvider);
  return cartAPI.getAdditionalCosts(cartCodes: ["BA3131"]); // <--- if I hardcode it in here, the problem will not occurred
});
```

Comment: Why do you need family modifier?

Comment: @ZakariaHossain to pass some strings as arguments/parameters

Comment: Post your view/widget codes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/family/#parameter-restrictions

This is the official documents for the Riverpod modifier **.family**.

```
For families to work correctly, it is critical for the parameter passed to a
provider to have a consistent hashCode and ==.
```

Since it is constant, you have to declare a class for it, you can create a class like below, using package **Equatable**.

```
class ExtraCostParameter extends Equatable {
  final List<String> cartCodesList;

  const ExtraCostParameter({required this.cartCodesList});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [cartCodesList];
}
```

And your new future provider will look like this.

```
final additionalCostsProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose.family<List<ExtraCost>, ExtraCostParameter>((ref, param) {
  final cartAPI = ref.watch(cartAPIProvider);
  return cartAPI.getAdditionalCosts(cartCodes: param.cartCodesList);
});
```

On the other hand, if your `List<String>` is not constant, you may want to use **.autoDispose**.

Hopefully it works.

Answer (score 2):

For families to work correctly, the parameter should either be a primitive (bool/int/double/String), a constant (providers), or an immutable object that overrides == and hashCode.
The problem is most likely because `cartCodes` is in the `build` method, so take out the `cartCodes` from the build method.

Try this :

```
class AdditionalCostPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const AdditionalCostPage({key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final List<String> cartCodes = carts.map((cart) => cart.code).toList();

@override
  Widget build(context, ref) {
    final additionalCostsProviderAsynValue = ref.watch(additionalCostsProvider(cartCodes));

    return Scaffold(
      body: additionalCostsProviderAsynValue.when(
        loading: () => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        error: (error, stackTrace) {
          return ErrorDisplay(
            onButtonClicked: () => ref.refresh(additionalCostsProvider(cartCodes)),
          );
        },
        data: (results) {

          return Container();

        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```